# Select2 data returning string instead of array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have a couple of `<select class="searchselect">` tags in my html, all filled with numeric values. I'm using the following piece of code to initialize Select2:

```
$(".searchselect").select2({
        ajax: {
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term,
                    '_token': token,
                    'data': function () {
                        var result = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        $('.searchselect').each(function () {
                            result[i] = $(this).val();
                            i++;
                        });

                        return result;
                    }
                };
            },
            url: function () {
                var type = $(this).attr('id');
                return '/test/get' + type;
            },
            cache: false,
            processResults: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        }
     });
```

In my php I have the following piece of code:

```
public function getTest()
{
    return json_encode($_POST['data']);
}
```

The returned php is gets logged in the console.

The result is a string with comma's to seperate the elements. However, this is not what it's supposed to be. It's something like this: `1,1,,,,,,` (the first two select fields filled and the rest still empty). It is sort of right, however, when I try to access the second element (the second 1 in the array), I need to access the 3rd element because the 2nd element is a comma.

```
public function getTest()
{
    return json_encode($_POST['data'][2]); // <--- this returns a comma instead of a 1
}
```

Where is it going wrong? Why is it using a plain string instead of an array?

Comment: json_decode instead of json_encode?

Comment: try `return $_POST['data'];` without `json_encode` since its already in JSON

Answer (score 0):

Change your function `getTest()` to

```
public function getTest()
{
    return json_decode($_POST['data']);
}
```

you are encoding json object to string instead of decoding it to array.